# jQuery string is parsed into object when hard coded but not when assigned to a variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I can't manage to find a solution, I've been stuck for hours and I think I'm missing something.

I have this code :

```
var s = hash.split("=").join(' : ');
var s_object =  JSON.parse(s);
$('.row').prepend(s_object);
```

The variable named 's' contains a string such as

> '{"furnitures" : "9", "clothes" : "5"}'

When the script above is executed, 's_object' doesn't become a hash. But when I do the following :

```
var s = '{"furnitures" : "9", "clothes" : "5"}';
var s_object =  JSON.parse(s);
$('.row').prepend(s_object);
```

or

```
var s_object =  JSON.parse('{"furnitures" : "9", "clothes" : "5"}');
$('.row').prepend(s_object);
```

everything works fine. Any idea what could cause this ?

Thanks!

## EDIT

Below is the exact code of my script :

```
var hash = '<%= @inventory.types %>';

var s = hash.split("=&gt;").join(' : ');
var s_object =  JSON.parse(s);
```

<%= @inventory.types %> is a serialized rails attribute (hash)

'hash' contains a string such as '{"furnitures"=>"9", "clothes"=>"5"}'

I had to use hash.split("=>") to successfully capture the greater-than symbol.

s_object doesn't become an object unless s value is hardcoded.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You can't really prepend objects, so you shouldn't be parsing the string to an object at all before inserting it, just insert it directly.

Comment: I need it to be an object... I just prepend it to check if it has become an object or not, I could have used type() instead.

Comment: You could have used the console, as in `console.log(s_object)`

Comment: @JulienSazert what is value of the original hash?? We need that value in order to test it without hard coding it

Comment: What is `hash`?

Comment: @HenryDev Hash is a string :

'{"furnitures"="9", "clothes"="5"}'

Comment: @zer00ne Hash is a string : 

'{"furnitures"="9", "clothes"="5"}'

Comment: what is source of that string, it's structure makes no sense? If you control creating the string , fix it's structure

Comment: @JulienSazert I just posted 2 solutions. Did that help?

Comment: @charlietfl see my edit above, I explain it all

Comment: Should be serializing the rails object to json in the first place and passing it directly to javascript variable without wrapping quotes so it would be a javascript object. Then you simply access the object properties directly

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your answer ! When I do var hash = '<%= \@inventory.types.to_json %>'; hash contains the right kind of string, but it remains a string I can't manage to make it a js hash when I parse it. And when I don't wrap the rails object with quotes it doesn't get assigned to the js variable, any idea ?

Comment: It would if you serialized the rails object to json using rails serializer

Comment: @JulienSazert I just updated my solution. Is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use "replace" javascript built-in function to make it look like JSON string then convert it to JSON Object:**

```
var hash = '{"furnitures"=>"9", "clothes"=>"5"}';
var result = hash.replace(/=>/g, ':');// {"furnitures":"9", "clothes":"5"}
```

**MY UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```js
var hash = '{"furnitures"=>"9", "clothes"=>"5"}';
var result = hash.replace(/=>/g, ':');
var s_object =  JSON.parse(result);
for(var i in s_object){
$('.row').prepend(i + " : " + s_object[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "row"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but it doesn't solve my problem, simply because 's' is not parsed into an object by JSON.parse(), i don't know why.

I edit my question with more info

Comment: @JulienSazert YES it's being parse after using JSON.parse which is why I can access its properties one by one or using the for loop (Its already an Object). My answer is working just fine

Comment: I agree with you, your answer is correct and should work, but for an obscure reason it doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: @JulienSazert I just updated my solution. Is that what you needed?